# CodeIgniter - Active Record returning empty results with Access ODBC

Tags: codeigniter, unixodbc, mdbtools

I'm connecting to an Access DB via mdbtools on a Linux system and on running any query via Active Record it returns an empty result. No errors or anything to show in the logs. Any ideas ? It connects to the database without a hitch and I have no problem accessing the tables or running queries with the default PHP method (e.g. odbc_exec(...)).

The DB Connection looks like this:

```
  $db['access']['hostname'] = 'MyDB';
  $db['access']['username'] = '';
  $db['access']['password'] = '';
  $db['access']['database'] = 'MyDB';
  $db['access']['dbdriver'] = 'odbc';
  $db['access']['dbprefix'] = '';
  $db['access']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
  $db['access']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
  $db['access']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
  $db['access']['cachedir'] = '';
  $db['access']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
  $db['access']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
  $db['access']['swap_pre'] = '';
  $db['access']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
  $db['access']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

The odbc.ini looks like:

```
[MyDB]
Description = My Database
Driver = /usr/lib64/libmdbodbc.so
Database = /var/database/MyDB.mdb
```

Connecting with:

```
$this->access = $this->load->database('access', TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have microsoft access database to test with the following configuration, but I think this should be able to give you an idea to experience with different configuration. You can specify [data source name](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html) in your configuration and I collected the settings from [codeigniter forum](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/183744/#869356) and merge with yours.

```
$db['access']['hostname'] = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=/var/database/MyDB.mdb";
$db['access']['username'] = "ADODB.Connection";
$db['access']['password'] = "";
$db['access']['database'] = "/var/database/MyDB.mdb";
$db['access']['dbdriver'] = "odbc";
$db['access']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['access']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['access']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['access']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['access']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['access']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['access']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
$db['access']['swap_pre'] = "";
$db['access']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['access']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```